# how to use C# concurrent dictionary in typescript?

Tags: c#, typescript, websocket, signalr

I am working on small c#/typescript based page. On back-end I have concurrent dictionary that holds key value pair of data. I have a class of object passed as values. Now server has to send that data to client as soon as data is requested. I have implemented function in typescript to get data from server. The function works but its not returning anything. Also we are using signalR to process data. I want to atleast get data on console. Please advise

c# code

```
MsgPrinterUIStatus.cs
using BaseLibrary;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Messages.PrinterStatusUI {
    public class MsgPrinterStatusUI : IMessage {
        // Identity Details
        public int ID;
        public string Name;
        public string Location;
        public string IP;
        public string Port;
        // Status Details
        public bool printerConnection;
        public string printerStatus;
        public bool paperOutFlg;
        public bool headUpFlg;
        public bool ribbonOutFlg;
        public char printMode;
        public int labelsRemaining;

        public string GetRoutingKey() {
            return RoutingKeys.PrinterStatusUI;
        }
    }
}

PrinterInfo.cs
namespace PrintAndApply.Class
{
    public class PrinterInfo
    {
        public  ConcurrentDictionary<int, MsgPrinterStatusUI> printerDetails = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, MsgPrinterStatusUI>();

    }
}

Hub service
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using NLog;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BaseLibrary;
using Messages.PrinterStatusUI;
using PrintAndApply.Class;

namespace PrintAndApply.Hubs
{
    public class PrinterHub : Hub
    {
        private static ILogger log = BaseLib.GetLogger("PrinterHub");
        public PrinterInfo printerInfo;

        public PrinterHub(PrinterInfo printerInfo)
        {
            Program.printer = printerInfo;
        }

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            log.Trace($"New client connected: {Context.ConnectionId}");
            log.Trace("Key" + Program.printer.printerDetails.Keys);
            foreach (var item in Program.printer.printerDetails)
            {
                log.Trace("CALLING FROM PRINTERHUB");
                log.Trace("Key---" + item.Key);
                log.Trace("Value----" + item.Value.Name);

                await Clients.All.SendAsync("ShowPrinterStatus", item.Key,
                        item.Value.Name, item.Value.printerStatus, item.Value.printerConnection);
            }

            log.Info("Sending Printer status to client");
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception ex)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("UserDisconnected", Context.ConnectionId);
            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(ex);
        }
    }
}

Typescript end
MsgPrinterUIStatus.ts
export interface MsgPrinterStatusUI {
    ID: number;
    Name: string;
    Location: string;
    IP: string;
    Port: string;
    printerConnection: boolean;
    printerStatus: string;
    paperOutFlg: boolean;
    headUpFlg: boolean;
    ribbonOutFlg: boolean;
    printMode: string;
    labelsRemaining: number;

}

signalr.service
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { MsgPrinterStatusUI } from '../Class/MsgPrinterStatusUI';
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalRService {

    //public data: MsgPrinterStatusUI[];
    public data: { [key: number]: MsgPrinterStatusUI[] } = {};

    private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;

    constructor(private appService: AppService) { }

    public startConnection = () => {
        this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(this.appService.hubUrl, {
                skipNegotiation: true,
                transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
            })
            .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
            .build();

        console.log("Starting.....");

        this.hubConnection
            .start()
            .then(() => console.log('Connection Established'))
            .catch(error => console.log('Failure with connection-->' + error))
    }

    public receivePrinterStatus = () => {
        console.log("Calling ReceivePrinterStatus");
        this.hubConnection.on("ShowPrinterStatus", (data) => {
            this.data = data;
            console.log(data);
            console.log("Yay, got printer status");

        });
    }
}

controller.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SignalRService } from '../Services/signal-r.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-printer-status',
  templateUrl: './printer-status.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./printer-status.component.scss']
})
export class PrinterStatusComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private signalRService: SignalRService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        console.log("Starting Connection");
        this.signalRService.startConnection();
        this.signalRService.receivePrinterStatus();
  }

}
```

Comment: Looking at your code , can you tell what is there on console.log. can you see 'Connection Established' ? Do you get breakpoint in signalR hub ?  Is printerInfo object constructor injected in PrinterHub , do you have DI setup correctly ?

Comment: yes, I can see connection established on console. Also I can see Calling ReceivePrinterStatus which i have passed within receivePrinterStatus function. but it shows nothing coming in data. Am i following correct syntax to store c# data on typescript end?

Comment: Can you add line console.log("On ShowPrinterStatus") in above  this.data = data; , is it printed on console ?

Comment: Added. it not getting printed,

Comment: Register your .on(...) function before starting the connection.

Answer (score 0):

1 Make sure your DI is setup correctly , do you get breakpoint in ctor if you debug.

```
public PrinterHub(PrinterInfo printerInfo)
        {
            Program.printer = printerInfo;
        }
```

2. Can you simplify this with single anonymous object

   await Clients.All.SendAsync("ShowPrinterStatus",new {Key=item.Key,
                      Name=item.Value.Name,Status=item.Value.printerStatus, Connection=item.Value.printerConnection});
3. Do not call receivePrinterStatus() rather use BehaviourSubject.

   public data= new BehaviorSubject(); 
   this.hubConnection.on("ShowPrinterStatus", (data) => {
          **this.data.next(data);**
           console.log(data);
           console.log("Yay, got printer status");
      });

export class PrinterStatusComponent implements OnInit {

```
constructor(private signalRService: SignalRService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {

    console.log("Starting Connection");
    this.signalRService.startConnection();
    this.signalRService.data.subscribe(data=>{

   });
```

}

Comment: My UI end is still showing empty.public receivePrinterStatus = () => {
        console.log("Calling ReceivePrinterStatus");
        this.hubConnection.on("ShowPrinterStatus", (data) => {
            this.dataSource.next(data);
            console.log("On Show PrinterStatus");
           // this.data = data;
            console.log(data);
            console.log("Yay, got printer status");
        }); 
    }

Comment: i have defined Behaviour subject as public dataSource: BehaviorSubject<MsgPrinterStatusUI[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);